# How to escape '-' hyphen symbol from xml in MathJax

Tags: mathjax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MathJax MathML Test Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/mml-chtml.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<math overflow="scroll"><mfrac><msup><msub><mi mathvariant="-italic">Q</mi><mrow><msub><mi mathvariant="italic">T</mi><mi mathvariant="italic">i</mi></msub><mo mathvariant="italic">max</mo></mrow></msub><mn mathvariant="normal">0.75</mn></msup><msup><mi mathvariant="italic">β</mi><mn mathvariant="normal">0.75</mn></msup></mfrac><mo>≤</mo><mn mathvariant="normal">5</mn><mo>×</mo><msub><mi mathvariant="italic">AEL</mi><msub><mi mathvariant="italic">T</mi><mi mathvariant="italic">i</mi></msub></msub><mo>×</mo><msup><msub><mi mathvariant="italic">Q</mi><msub><mi mathvariant="italic">T</mi><mi mathvariant="italic">m</mi></msub></msub><mrow><mo>−</mo><mn mathvariant="normal">0.25</mn></mrow></msup><mo></mo></math>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Getting parsing error with new CDN https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/mml-chtml.js

Comment: get Math output error

Comment: `mathvariant="-italic"` is not a valid math variant, and that is causing MathJax to fail when trying to locate that variant.

Comment: we don't have control on the xml, we get it from third party. Is there any way we can skip that error and just display the formula?

Comment: Well, the first thing you should do is get your third-part providers to generate valid MathML, which they aren't.  From MathJax's side, you could add a MathML input jax post-filter that walks the MathML tree and checks the values of the `mathvariant` attributes and replaces invalid ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a configuration you can use to post-filter the MathML to fix the invalid `-italic` math variant value.

```js
MathJax = {
  startup: {
    ready() {
      MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
      MathJax.startup.input[0].postFilters.add(({data}) => {
        data.walkTree(node => {
          if (node.attributes) {
            if (node.attributes.get('mathvariant') === '-italic') {
              node.attributes.set('mathvariant', 'italic');
            }
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Place this in a `<script>` tag just **before** the script that loads `mml-html.js`.